# Google Apps Script deployment does not return same value as editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, web-applications, google-docs, google-docs-api

Problem: When i run the Google Apps Script in the editor, it works fine and returns the selected text from Google Docs.
When I test the deployment, or use the Retrieve Text From Google Docs button on my extension, the JSON coming from google apps script is "Nothing is selected", which you can see in the else statement.

I would guess that the problem is in var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

This is because the if statement is not being performed due to the variable selection being empty.

I have added all the needed scopes to the appsscript.json

I also tried a 2nd implementation using var selection = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getSelection();, nevertheless it still didnt work.

What could possibly be the problem? Ive been stuck on this for 3 days straight and cannot find a solution.

> 

```
 function doGet() {  

  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  
  Logger.log(selection);

  if (selection && selection.getRangeElements().length > 0) {
    console.log("Document loaded.")
    var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
    var firstElement = elements[0].getElement().asText().getText();
    console.log(firstElement);
    console.log(typeof(firstElement));

    var text = JSON.parse('{"output":"'+firstElement+'"}');
    console.log(text);
    console.log("we passed line 10");
  } else {
    var text = JSON.parse('{"output":"Nothing is selected"}');
  }

  console.log(text);
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(text);
  console.log(jsonString);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(jsonString).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  

}
```

I will attach the output when the script is run on the editor vs when the script is run on deployment, with the same text selection in docs.

[Run on Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NwO3.png)
[Run on Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRHLV.png)

Comment: When you run from editor, I'm assuming your running it from an active document with something selected. 'doGet' is run through an HTTP request, so there is no active document or selection in that environment.  You can change that to use [DocumentApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)) and perhaps some sort of seach string to find the text your are interested in.

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned, I tried doing what you said but I still got the same result

Comment: Yeah it may not work at all from a web app because there is no active document and in order to have a selection you must have a user interface and from a web app deployment the code could run during a time when there is no user.  Try wrapping a try catch block around the code.  Or have you checked the execution logs.  I'm guessing you'll get some sort of error saying that you can not do this with in this context or something like that.

Comment: In the current stage, when the `getSelection()` is run from the outside of Google Document (using Web Apps), `null` is returned with both `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection()` and `DocumentApp.openById("###").getSelection()`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. So, I'm worried that the answer to `What could possibly be the problem?` might be no. But, I cannot know your actual expected result. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the answer to your question. So, in this case, I posted only the reason for your current issue as a comment.